# Finding maximum values in multiple ranges specified by additional condition

Tags: excel, max, pivot-table, array-formulas, vba

I would like to use a PivotTable to find the numbers in a class, based on the class in an adjacent column. However, the data I am creating the PivotTable from has to be presented as below:

```
No. in Class:    Class:
1                Class 1
2                Class 1
3                Class 1
1                Class 2
2                Class 2
3                Class 3
```

This means I need to find the maximum value in column A but only within a specific range based on the class number in column B. I cannot just have `1` for the class, it must be `class 1`.

Comment: Title is confusing: Max value by very definition should be only one. I am editing your question for better clarity. Regards,

Comment: You could use COUNTIF() directly on the "class" column, unless for some reason you'd expect a different result from getting the max from the first column.

Comment: Do you want to find continous groups of same class, or maximum among all entries with same class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Class` is in B1, maybe:

```
 =MAX(IF(B:B=B2,A:A))
```

in C2 entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter and copied down to suit.

---

oOPs! OP did ask "with a pivot table":

[image: SO27515853 PT example]

Comment: Doesn't this give the overall maximum? E.g. of you add for last row `4, Class 3` you get 4 everywhere.

Comment: The `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` isn't immediately obvious :) Array formulas heh. Nice answer!